# ActiveRecord speed up `where.not` query

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

I have a query that is taking getting significantly slowed down when an `not` clause is added to the query.

```
# query is 13.6ms
FbGroupApplication.select(
:fb_id
).group(:fb_id
).having('count(fb_id) <= 6'
)


# 3,468ms with `where.not` clause. the array is large (5-10k)
FbGroupApplication.where.not(
fb_id: ids
).select(:fb_id
).group(:fb_id
).having('count(fb_id) <= 6'
)
```

I added an index on `fb_id`. However, one thing to note is that it's a text field and the values are about 12 character strings of numbers

How can I speed up this query?

Comment: How do you determine which ids to include in the array? Are they always the same or will it depend?

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge always different. ended up comparing the ids in ruby and it's much faster

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the ids are variable and due to the big number of them I guess your best approach would be to create a temporary table and insert the ids you want to exclude there.

Then query using LEFT JOIN, SELECT the ids that don't exist on the temporary table and DROP the table afterwards

Comment: It's also worth ensuring those IDs are set as primary keys or are augmented with a `UNIQUE` index.

Comment: thanks. ended up comparing the ids in ruby and it's much faster